# ReExporting a variable to the environment from a bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I have the following bash script.

```
export KEY=A
run_command_that_uses_KEY
...
export KEY=B
run_command_that_uses_KEY
```

export exports the variable assignment to sub-shells, i.e. shells which are started as child processes of the shell containing the export directive. The command-line environment is the parent of the script's shell, so it does not see the variable assignment. How can I force the parent shell to export the correct key? Can I source the bash script in the bash script itself or something?

Comment: You seem to be making a sharp turn when you get to "How can I force the parent shell...". What are you trying to do?

Comment: The second `run_command_that_uses_KEY` still gets A instead of B.

Comment: Are you sure that's what's happening? It should get B. In fact, you only have to use `export` the first time; after that, the shell knows it's exported, and changes will be exported.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a problem with your variables not being exported. You can trivially verify that this works correctly from the `bash` side:

```
export KEY=A
bash -c 'echo $KEY'
export KEY=B
bash -c 'echo $KEY'
```

The problem in your case is more likely that your program is single instance.

If you try the above with `firefox` or `gedit`, you'll find that variables work the first time but not the second time.

This is because the first time, the program starts from scratch, while the second time, it just sends the old process a message to open a new window.

You can try killing all the processes related to the task before invoking it again.

Comment: That was it the `run_command_that_uses_KEY` was still get the B, but the env `KEY` was B, killed it right before and that worked.